# Sets of symbols contained in contiguous substrings

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet with $m$ different symbols.

Let $s$ be a string in $\Sigma$ of length $n$. Assume that every symbol in $\Sigma$ occurs in $s$ at least once (so $n\geq m$).

Let $\mathrm{Sub}(s)$ be the set of contiguous substrings of $s$. Let $P(\Sigma)$ be the power set of $\Sigma$. There is a map $f:\mathrm{Sub}(s)\to P(\Sigma)$ sending a substring to the set of symbols it contains.

For fixed $m$ and $n$ what is the maximum cardinality of the image of $\mathrm{Sub}(s)\to P(\Sigma)$?

For instance if $m=n$ then $f$ is injective so we get$$1+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$different subsets.

Comment: can you share any background for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, brute-force search with some Julia code gives following small values $C(m,n)$ for the maximum number of subsets covered by the contiguous substrings:

\begin{array}{rr|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
&& n\\
&& 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
\hline
m & 2 & 4 & = \\
  & 3 &  & 7 & 8 & = \\
  & 4 &  &   & 11 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & = \\
  & 5 &  &   &    & 16 & 19 & 21 & 23 & 25 & 27 & 30 & 31 & 32 & = \\
  & 6 &  &   &    &    & 22 & 26 & 29 & 32 & 35 & 38 & 41 & 45 & 48 \\
  & 7 &  &   &    &    &    & 29 & 34 & 38 & 42 & 46 & 50 & 54 & 58 \\
  & 8 &  &   &    &    &    &    & 37 & 43 & 48 & 53 & 58 & 63 & 68 \\
  & 9 &  &   &    &    &    &    &    & 46 & 53 & 59 & 65 & 71 & 77 \\
  & 10&  &   &    &    &    &    &    &    & 56 & 64 & 71 & 78 & 85 \\
  & 11&  &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    & 67 & 76 & 84 & 92 \\
  & 12&  &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    & 79 & 89 & 98 \\
  & 13&  &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    & 92 & 103 \\
  & 14&  &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &    & 106 \\
\end{array}

"=" means that the rest of the row repeats the last value, that is, there is a string that exhibits all $2^m$ subsets (adding more length will not change this).

Looking at diagonals:

- The main diagonal is as described in the question.
- The first superdiagonal 4,8,13,19,26,34,43,53,64,76 has [one OEIS match](https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C8%2C13%2C19%2C26%2C34%2C43%2C53%2C64%2C76&sort=&language=&go=Search), A034856 "a(n) = binomial(n+1, 2) + n - 1 = n*(n + 3)/2 - 1".
- The second superdiagonal has no OEIS entry but OEIS [guesses](https://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C14%2C21%2C29%2C38%2C48%2C59%2C71%2C84&sort=&language=&go=Search) it to be a quadratic.  Same with third superdiagonal.
- The fourth superdiagonal, starting from 16,25,35,46,58,71,85,100,116,133,151 has [two matches](https://oeis.org/search?q=16%2C25%2C35%2C46%2C58%2C71%2C85%2C100%2C116%2C133%2C151&sort=&language=&go=Search) (but different values before the 16).

If we write $T(m)$ for the smallest $n$ where $2^m$ appears, $T$ forms a sequence that starts 1,2,4,8,13, which matches many things in OEIS. Examples of shortest strings where all $2^m$ subsets of alphabet $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ appear are:

\begin{array}{l|l}
m & T(m) \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 12 \\
3 & 4 & 1231 \\
4 & 8 & 12314234 \\
5 & 13 & 1234512413524 \\
\end{array}

### Proof sketch for first superdiagonal

From the small values one can conjecture that $C(m,m+1) = \frac{1}{2}m^2 +
 \frac{3}{2}m - 1$.  I think this is true for all $m \ge 2$, here's a (sort of) proof.

Let us construct the string letter by letter.  At each position we have
two kinds of choices: a letter already seen, or an unseen letter.  In
the second case we can, without loss of generality, pick the *smallest
unseen letter*; this is just a matter of permutation of the alphabet.
In the first case, it does no good to pick the previous letter again,
so we rule that out.

Consider a string over alphabet $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ of length $n=m+1$.
Because each letter has to appear at least once, we have only one
letter $q$ appearing twice, with the repeat occurring at some position $p$.
So we have only a small number of strings to consider. The strings are of the form:

$$
1,2,\ldots,p-1,q,p,\ldots,m
$$

where at position $p$ we have picked an already seen letter $q \in
\{1,2,\ldots,p-2\}$.  The rest of the string is forced because we must pick all the remaining $m-p+1$ letters, and w.l.o.g. we can just take them in order.

For example, with $m=5$ and $n=6$, our candidate strings and the
numbers of subsets covered are as follows.  The repeated letter
$q$ is underlined.

\begin{array}{ll}
 12\underline{1}345 & 16 \\
 123\underline{1}45 & 17 \\
 123\underline{2}45 & 16 \\
 1234\underline{1}5 & 18 \\
 1234\underline{2}5 & 17 \\
 1234\underline{3}5 & 16 \\
 12345\underline{1} & 19 \\
 12345\underline{2} & 18 \\
 12345\underline{3} & 17 \\
 12345\underline{4} & 16
\end{array}

Taking $p=n$ and $q=1$ we get the string that has first all letters $1,\ldots,m$ in order, then repeats the 1.  This gives the conjectured value.  I believe that for other choices of $p$ and $q$ one can show that the result is smaller (for all $m$) but I didn't check the details.

### The $m=6$ case

**Update (25.5.2021).** We have $C(6,24)=64$. There are several 24-digit strings attaining this maximum, for example $$123456 \; 532614 \; 251364 \; 265143$$ (spaces just for easier reading).  This string begins with 1...m, supporting Per Alexandersson's conjecture in the comments.

It also seems (by about 56 cpu-hours of computation) that $C(6,23)=63$, so the $T$ sequence would begin $1,2,4,8,13,24$.  This has [7 matches in OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C13%2C24&go=Search), but I could not easily see a connection to the present problem in any of them.

### Previous research on a similar problem

A closely related problem is found in Lipski (1978), "[On strings containing all subsets as substrings](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(78)90157-7)", Discrete Mathematics, 21(3), 253-259.

There the problem is to find a string that contains *all* subsets $S \subseteq\Sigma$ as substrings of length $|S|$.  Note two differences: only the maximal case (*all* subsets), and the substrings have to be of minimal length $|S|$. In the current question longer substrings are allowed, for example using substring $1234245$ for the subset $12345$.

Anyway, for this version and $m=1,\ldots,5$ Lipski lists solutions
$$1, 12, 1231, 12342413, 1234512413524.$$  He also proves asymptotic lower and upper bounds of $(2/\pi m)^{1/2}2^m$ and $(2/\pi)2^m$, respectively.

Comment: The extremal words are reminicient of Super permutations, https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Superpermutation

Comment: Also, instead of 12314234, one can take 12343142, so that the extremal word starts with 1,2...m. Perhaps this choice is always possible?

Comment: @Per: True, and also the question is somehow similar to (and different from) de Bruijn sequences, which contain all possible *substrings* of a given length. But now we are seeking all *subsets* of the alphabet.

Comment: At least one can, without loss of generality, start with increasing numbers 1,2,... because whenever you pick an unseen letter, it does not matter which unseen letter you pick, so you can as well pick the smallest unseen letter. However there is always also the choice of picking a seen letter again, and I don't know if one can continue in order up to 1,2,...,m ?

Comment: Right, that's a conjecture. But also, one can assume no two adjacent letters are equal, which makes the search a bit smaller. I wonder if there is a recursive way to combine two extremal words, to produce one containing all subsets for one letter more. This can be used to create an upper bound at least for T(m)...

Answer (score 0):

Using some Mathematica, we we let $h(m,n)$
be defined as
$$
 h(m,n) = \max_{f : [n] \to [m] } | \mathrm{image}(f) |.
$$
For small combinations of $(m,n)$, we get the table
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 2 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\
 2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
 2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 16 & 19 & 21 & 23 \\
 2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 16 & 22 & 26 & 29 \\
\end{array}
$$
The code used here is:

```
cardSort[wrd_List] := Prepend[
   Union[Join @@ Table[
      Union[wrd[[i ;; j]]],
      {i, Length@wrd}, {j, i, Length@wrd}]]
   , {}];
h2[m_, n_] := 
  h2[m, n] = Max@Table[Length@cardSort[w], {w, Tuples[Range[m], n]}];
```

OLD Answer:
If we instead set
$$
 h'(m,n) = \max_{f : [n] \to [m] } | \mathrm{image}(f) |.
$$
where the we now map to $f$ to  the set of all contiguous substrings,
we get the table
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
 1 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 21 & 27 \\
 1 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 13 & 18 & 24 & 31 \\
 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 14 & 19 & 25 & 32 \\
 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 26 & 33 \\
\end{array}
$$
Some search in the OEIS suggests that we (almost always have)
$$
h'(m,n) = \text{Number of edges in $(m+1)$-partite Turán graph of order $n+1$.}
$$

The Mathematica code I used here is

```
card[wrd_List] := 
  Length@Union[
    Join @@ Table[wrd[[i ;; j]], {i, Length@wrd}, {j, i, Length@wrd}]];
h[m_, n_] := h[m, n] = Max@Table[card[w], {w, Tuples[Range[m], n]}];
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this answer seems to miss the part "contiguous substrings" of the question.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen wrd[[i ;; j]] is a contiguous substring, starting at i, ending at j.
But note that the code checks ALL words, and looks for maximum size of image set.
I think however that my code misses the empty set, so one should add +1 to get your results, I guess.

Comment: EDIT: Ah, I missed the projection where one does not keep the order of elements in the substring!